# How to prevent UITableViewCell from being visually deselected right at tap?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I use the following to set the selected backgroud color of my `UITableViewCell`s:

```
    let backgroundColorView = UIView()
    backgroundColorView.backgroundColor = .red
    UITableViewCell.appearance().selectedBackgroundView = backgroundColorView
```

When I tap to select them, the cell briefly flashes red and then return to the `backgroundColor` I've set.

When I add:

```
    if cell.isSelected
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = .red
    }
```

to `cellForRowAt indexPath`, the cell becomes red when I scroll it out of sight and back again.

How can I make sure that the cell remains red immediately after I tap it?

EDIT:
If I add the following code to `cellForRowAt`, things work as expected:

```
    let backgroundColorView = UIView()
    backgroundColorView.backgroundColor = .red
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = backgroundColorView
```

Could be an iOS bug?

Comment: @matt I don't do anything in `didSelect` that could cause this. If I remove setting `UITableViewCell.appearance().selectedBackgroundView` (from my `SceneDelegate`) the cells select nicely showing the default gray. Any idea what could be wrong with that?

Comment: From the docs: "To support appearance customization, a class must conform to the UIAppearanceContainer protocol and relevant accessor methods must be marked with UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR." Is the accessor for UITableViewCell `selectedBackgroundView` marked in that way? If not, no promise was made that you could use the appearance proxy in this manner, and there's no bug.